# using sidekiq and Rmagick to alter images uploaded with carrierwave in the background

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave, sidekiq, rmagick

I have a rails app in which a user can upload images that will then be altered into the background and emailed to them.  I am using carrierwave and in my perform_asycn method, I am passing in the tempfile/path to my sidekiq worker, however, I get an error saying that the file doesn't exsist.

controller

```
ImageWorker.perform_asycn(params["image"].tempfile.path)
```

class ImageWorker

```
def perform(path)
  avatar = ImageList.new(path).last
 #do other stuff
end
```

I get an ImageMagick error saying unable to open image: No such file or directory.  Just to test, I tried to use Rmagick in the controller before I pass the path argument to the worker and everything works fine.  I'm guessing carrierwave gets rid of the file once its passes it out of the controller but I don't know how I can access the file I want in the sidekiq worker.

Answer (score 1):

This is appears because your temporary file was removed after complete request. So, in you worker you a trying to open file which has been removed.

So, in you case I recommend to use [carrierwave_backgrounder](https://github.com/lardawge/carrierwave_backgrounder). It should handle this case correctly.